# Make own intellisense in vs code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, intellisense

My Unity Intellisense doesn't work very well, so I want to build my own Unity Intellisense.

I found that snippets are nice stuff to build, but there is some trouble in it.

```
<!-- language: lang-json -->

    "Vector2":{
            "prefix": "Vector2",
            "body":[
                "Vector2${1|.right, .left, .down, .top|}"
            ],
            "description": "Representation of 2D vectors and points"
        }
```

Thanks to this json code I could make it partially: [image: partially]

However, I want to express like this: [image: wantimg]
prompt some information message box for the method.

But I couldn't make it. I have no idea, how to build intellisense like that.

How can I build it?